# I need to find top 2 employees with highest salary in a column without using any predefined functions in mysql

Tags: mysql

Table

Employee_number  Salary

..........................

1                 1000

2                  900

3                  1500

4                   600

5                   50

6                    79

I have already tried using 
............................

select employee_number,salary from employees where (3-1) = (select count(distinct(*)) from employees) order by salary desc;

output
...............
Empty set (0.00 sec)

when i use limit function i am getting the output

Comment: `"where (3-1) = (select count(distinct(*)) from employees)"` - ... Huh?  All of those records are distinct, so what is that count going to be?  6?  And 3-1 (otherwise known as 2) isn't going to equal 6.  What are you *trying* to do in that `WHERE` clause?  If you just need to find the two highest salaries, why not just order by that salary column descending and take the first two records?

Comment: how can i select first two records without using a predefined limit or rank functions

Comment: You limit the results to the first 2 records by using `LIMIT 2`.  Why on Earth can't you use standard SQL functionality in SQL?  That's what it's there for.

Comment: The question itself is not to use limit function

Comment: select employeenumber from tblemployees where (5-1) = (select count(distinct(employeenumber)) from tblemployees where count(employeenumber)<=5);

Comment: but it says invalid use of group function

Answer (score 1):

How about

`SELECT employee_number,salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2;`

Comment: I am not supposed to use row number or limit functions(mysql predefined)